# Как открыть проект на Vue.js в VS2017?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, vue.js, webpack

Сразу оговорюсь, на Vue.js не программировал, есть небольшой опыт со старым AngularJS, да и тот в Notepad++

---

Я создал проект на Vue.js по следующей минимальным шагам:

```
npm install --global vue-cli
vue init webpack
```

Мастеру указал следующие параметры:

```
? Generate project in current directory? Yes
"git" ?? ????? ???????? ??? ?????
????????, ??????? ?????? ??? ?????? ????.
? Project name myproject
? Project description myproject
? Author I'm
? Vue build (Use arrow keys)
? Vue build standalone
? Install vue-router? Yes
? Use ESLint to lint your code? Yes
? Pick an ESLint preset Standard
? Set up unit tests Yes
? Pick a test runner jest
? Setup e2e tests with Nightwatch? No
? Should we run `npm install` for you after the project has been created? (recommended) npm
```

Получил вот такую структуру проекта:

[image: структура дерева файлов проекта созданного по шаблону webpack]

---

А теперь вопрос: как мне этот дело открыть в Visual Studio 2017 Community?

Могу открыть просто каталог, и даже синтаксис в template и style подсвечивается, но вот с scripts беда - ни подсветки, ни подсказок.

Как победить?

Comment: просто совет: используйте @vue/cli - это новая версия 3.x,  vue-cli - это предыдущая, старая.

Comment: Это критично, что вы используете именно Visual Studio? Если нет используйте VSCode - это быстрее и намного комфортней, нет ничего лишнего, для Vue есть набор дополнений, работает быстро.    https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Благодарю за наводку на @vue/cli - действительно выглядит поинтереснее)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вам нужно, чтобы VS распознавал js код в vue?
Если я правильно понял, то, как вариант, попробуй установить дополнительный пакет, например такой:

> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur

Comment: Спасибо, попробуем поиграться